# nginx istio url not resolved and return 426 status code

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, istio, nginx-config

i have a service that name is `image-api`. the image-api is accessible in pod but nginx return 426 status code

after running this command return the expected data

```
curl image-api.gateways.svc.cluster.local:8000
```

but nginx return 426 status code.

if replace the native url of image-api by istio url then nginx return 200 status code.

the `/etc/nginx.nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 8;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    resolver kube-dns.kube-system valid=10s;

    server_tokens off;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location ~ ^/(\w+) {
            # ISTIO URL
        proxy_pass http://image-api.gateways.svc.cluster.local:8000$request_uri;
            # MAIN URL
#       proxy_pass http://image-api.main.svc.cluster.local:8000$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fariya-rahmat. his answer helps me to find the answer.

add `proxy_http_version 1.1` is necessary but it's not enough.

the main problem is `proxy_set_header Host $host;` the `envoy proxy` detects the target service by hostname and it is wrong. if delete `proxy_set_header` the hostname is set automatically based on `proxy_pass`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [document](https://httpstatuses.com/426):

> A 426 status code is caused when a client is attempting to upgrade a
> connection to a newer version of a protocol, but the server is
> refusing to do so.
>
> This can happen for several reasons, including:
>
> 1. Incompatibility between the client and server versions of the protocol.
> 2. The server may not support the requested version of the protocol.
> 3. The server may be configured to only allow certain versions of the protocol to be used.
> 4. The server may be experiencing technical issues or undergoing maintenance that prevents it from upgrading the connection.

You need to upgrade your HTTP protocol version in NGINX config like there:

This route is for a legacy API, which enabled NGINX cache for performance reason, but in this route's proxy config, it missed a shared config [proxy_http_version 1.1](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version), which default to use HTTP 1.0 for all NGINX upstream.

And Envoy will return HTTP 426 if the request is HTTP 1.0.